# Traversing Xml using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I'm trying to get data from 2 different parts of XML :

```
<product>
    <global>
        <identification>
            <suCode>
                <![CDATA[52774]]>
            </suCode>
            <suExtCode>
                <![CDATA[0]]>
            </suExtCode>
            <code>
                <![CDATA[2000000370804]]>
            </code>
        </identification>
    </global> 
    <PARTS>
        <part1>
            <identification>
                <code>
                    <![CDATA[2000000370828]]>
                </code>
                <lvarCoDE>
                    <![CDATA[0]]>
                </lvarCoDE>
                <linked>
                    <![CDATA[0]]>
                </linked>
                <codeChild>
                    <![CDATA[2000000370804]]>
                </codeChild>
            </identification>
        </part1>
        <part2>
            <identification>
                <gtin>
                    <![CDATA[2000000370835]]>
                </gtin>
                <lvarCoDE>
                    <![CDATA[0]]>
                </lvarCoDE>
                <linked>
                    <![CDATA[0]]>
                </linked>
                <codeChild>
                    <![CDATA[2000000370828]]>
                </codeChild>
            </identification> 
        </part2>
    </PARTS>
</product>
```

the global and the parts  are related by the `linked` tag  and the `suExtCode` and the different parts of the second bloc of the xml are also related by the `code` tag and `codeChild` tag

like : 52774 -> 2000000370828 -> 2000000370835

Is there any way to create a treeview for this xml using javascript ?

the XML i need to have at the end :

```
<product>
    <suCode>
        <code>
            <![CDATA[2000000370828]]>
        </code>
        <lvarCoDE>
            <![CDATA[0]]>
        </lvarCoDE>
        <linked>
            <![CDATA[0]]>
        </linked>
        <codeChild>
            <gtin>
                <![CDATA[2000000370835]]>
            </gtin>
            <lvarCoDE>
                <![CDATA[0]]>
            </lvarCoDE>
            <linked>
                <![CDATA[0]]>
            </linked>
            <codeChild>
                <![CDATA[2000000370828]]>
            </codeChild>
        </codeChild>
    </suCode>
</product>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Without jQuery :

If you want something that works without jQuery, consider this :

```
var xmlStr = '<product><global><identification>...'</product>';

var xmlDoc =  (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
```

You can use DOM methods like [`getElementsById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) or [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) to move through your `xmlDoc` tree :

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('identification');
```

See [**the MDN docs on `DOMParser`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

---

#### With jQuery :

As you put [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) among your tags, I assume you're using jQuery.

If you use jQuery, it's as simple as this :

```
var xmlStr = '<product><global><identification>...'</product>';

var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlStr);
```

You can then wrap your `xmlDoc` in a jQuery object :

```
var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
```

After that, you can move through your `$xml` tree "the jQuery way" :

```
$xml.find('identification');
```

See [**the official documentation for `jQuery.parseXML()`**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/).

---

Comment: Thank you @John, considering the XML above , i totally see that your answer would do the work, but with a bigger XML, with block related to each other as mentioned above , you'd it be time consuming to traverse the XML file with this method ?

Comment: @Orionbelt : So, what exactly is it you want to do with the content of this XML?

Comment: I need to create another XML out of it , containing a parent and child relation between each blocks of the XML we had at first place : 
please see update !

Comment: @Orionbelt : The only thing you can do, really, is (1) parse your source XML (as explained in my answer), (2) create an empty target empty XML document, (3) loop through the components of your parsed source XML (like you would loop through the `<li>` elements of a `<lu>` tag if it was HTML) and then (4) append the corresponding elements from the source XML doc to your target XML doc. There is no shortcut to that, I'm afraid. That's as simple as it gets!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is parse the XML like this.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xml= parser.parseFromString(dataFromXMLFile,"text/xml");
```

With `dataFromXMLFile` being what you've provided as an XML. After this, the `xml` variable can be used much like html through the `document` object.

```
xml.getElementsByTagName('codeChild') // Returns an array of the codeChild elements.
```